# Dark mode not applied to all the applications

Tags: themes, appearance, qt5

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 and switched to dark mode from appearance settings but it is not working on some applications like virtual box

[image]

Comment: `virtualbox` is a Qt5 program and not GTK you've tagged.  What Qt5 theme have you chosen (is it *light* for example?)

Comment: Where I can find it? I am new to ubuntu

Comment: I don’t use QT apps but you might find some info here: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/11/change-qt5-apps-theme-look-native-ubuntu-20-04/amp/

Comment: Your theme won't work in snap nor flatpak applications either. Because of the sandboxing.

Comment: Found the solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ManjaroLinux/comments/j5e9l2/comment/g7rwr3r/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). Qt5ct is easier to configure than kvantum